# PHP--Convert Boolean Value to String

Tags: php, arrays, boolean

I am trying to convert Boolean values stored in an associative array into strings.  The array has string, date and Boolean values stored in it.

I get the expected when I print out the array values.  Boolean true prints as 1 and false prints nothing.  I want for Boolean true to print "True" and Boolean false to print "False".

I have tried testing for "" values for false with no luck.  I have tried testing for 1 and "1" for true with no success.  I have tried testing using both filter_var and is_bool with no success.  I found nothing on the web to point me to a solution.

Does anyone have a suggetion?

Thanks.

Bill

Answer (score 1):

hope this helps

```
foreach ($arr as $dateValue => $bool )
{
 echo "$datValue"
 echo $bool ? 'true' : 'false';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ternary operator to check against the boolean values:

```
$boolean = true;
echo $boolean ? 'true' : 'false'; #outputs the string true
$boolean = false;
echo $boolean ? 'true' : 'false'; #outputs the string false
```

Answer (score 0):

Well looks like when you loop the array to show each field, you'll have to do something like

```
if(is_bool($value)) echo $value ? 'True' : 'False';
```